# How to access a property located in different DLL

Tags: c#, .net

I have a property called "Dynamic" and method `SetDefaultValues()` located in same  DLL. property is shown below

```
public class ManagedProperty: DataModelObject, ISerializable 
{

    public bool Dynamic 
    {
        get 
        {
            return m_dynamic;
        }
        set 
        {
            m_dynamic = value;
        }
    }
    private bool m_dynamic = true;
}
```

method SetDefaultValues()  will default all the values in to defult.The problem now i am facing is whenever i restart my window service ,it is defaulting from original value which is a bug. So the condition which i wanted is whenever  "Dynamic" property is false it should not defult

So the problem causing code in window service is shown below. Debugger shows property Dynamic always true

```
                          for (int i = 0; i < allObjects.Count; i++)
                                    {
                                        DataModelObject dmo = (DataModelObject)allObjects.GetAt(i);
                                        dmo.SatisfyGRs(allObjects); // Satisfy all GUID references.
                                        if (dmo is ManagedDevice)
                                        {
                                            ManagedDevice md = (ManagedDevice)dmo;

                                            // Set default values for user defined properties
                                            if (md.SetDefaultValues())
                                            {
                                                SaveObject(md, false);
                                            }
                                            md.CheckThresholds();   // Check thresholds on all properties
                                        }
                                    }
```

I modified it like shown below, but i dont know it is not working correctly ,and setting in to default values. Can anybody tell me what is going wrong here, or everything is correct and  i need to check other environments

```
                          for (int i = 0; i < allObjects.Count; i++)
                                    {
                                        DataModelObject dmo = (DataModelObject)allObjects.GetAt(i);
                                        dmo.SatisfyGRs(allObjects); // Satisfy all GUID references.
                                        if (dmo is ManagedDevice)
                                        {
                                            ManagedDevice md = (ManagedDevice)dmo;
                                            ManagedProperty userprop = new ManagedProperty();
                                            if (userprop.Dynamic == false){
                                            // Set default values for user defined properties
                                            if (md.SetDefaultValues())
                                            {
                                                SaveObject(md, false);
                                            }}
                                            md.CheckThresholds();   // Check thresholds on all properties
                                        }
                                    }
```

Comment: This is all in memory, right? When you restart the service, you lose everything in memory. If you want to maintain state between restarts, then you need to persist that state (file, DB, etc...) before restarting, then load that state after the restart.

Comment: @Bob Horn , no before restarting i saved  and i can see values in database xml, but when i restart everything defalut. My deugger is not attaching properly and how i came to know this problem causing mean ,when i commented this code , it working correctly

Comment: Do you just have a mistake in your `if` statement? You said when it's false it should not default. Shouldn't your statement be like this then: `if (userprop.Dynamic != false)`? As it stands right now, it will default only when it's already false.

Comment: @Bob Horn it is not the problem ,i cahnged to true, but now i understood my debuuger always shows userprop.Dynamic = true, why it is always shows true i dont know may be the default value of property private bool m_dynamic = true;

Comment: It always shows true because you initialized it that way: `private bool m_dynamic = true;`

Comment: Your for loop could be more elegant as well: `foreach (DataModelObject dmo in allObjects)`. Then you wouldn't have to get and cast each object within the loop; you could just use dmo as-is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're setting m_dynamic to true in a field initializer:

```
private bool m_dynamic = true;
```

Then you have this code:

```
ManagedProperty userprop = new ManagedProperty();
if (userprop.Dynamic == false)
```

How could it ever be anything other than true? When you instantiate a ManagedProperty, Dynamic will be true every time.

Comment: no this will not work , i need a mechanism to send Dynamic values current value to window service